# Add title to each item of Gallery Image

Tags: android, gallery

I hava a Gallery Image, and I want to add a title below each item (image).

This is my actual adapter :

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View inputView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    EmergencyCall item = listEmergencyCall.get(position);

    if (inputView == null) {
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      inputView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
      holder.imageView = (ImageView) inputView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      holder.textView = (TextView) inputView.findViewById(R.id.titletxt);

      inputView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) inputView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.getImg());
    holder.textView.setText(item.getTitle());
    return inputView;
  }

  public static class ViewHolder {
    public RelativeLayout backgroundLayout;
    public ImageView imageView;
  }
}
```

This is the xml file :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/background_layout"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titletxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EIDT : this should be work now. Now titles are added to the Gallery image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a TextView and ImageView in Relative Layout or FrameLayout like this :-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/thumbHolder">

    <com.views.RotatingGallery
            android:id="@+id/emergency_call_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

then in your getView() method of adapter you can inflate this xml and set the text(title) to textView .. it should work fine .. ping me if you get it working !!

this should work !!

Comment: I added my main.xml in my question. I can't follow we. Can you be more  specified please ?

Comment: instead of LinearLayout use FrameLayout as it will place your textView over the ImageView

Comment: I have 1 error in fact : 1/ The methode put(String, Drawable)int he type HashMap<String, Drawable> is not applicable for this arguments :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39053/discussion-between-r4jiv007-and-farbhyn)

Comment: It works, now I can see titles :D thanks a lot sir. You saved my day :) I edited my question to help others